# How to I get my inputs to be within the form-container on mobile screen size?

Tags: html, css

At about 600px, you can see the outside grey container start to push inward on the right hand side while the left side stays the same even though I do have 95vw set. Then, at around 558px, you can see how the input field goes outside the container even though I want it to be within the grey container. My media query that is set at max width 500px though seems to work and the input elements do resize, while my other media query does not seem to work. So how do I fix those problems? I do have bootstrap but only for styling purposes like the inputs and buttons. I am trying to do this without the grid system.

```
<div class="v-header container">
        <div class="fullscreen-video-container">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="/videoImage/Hourglass.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="component-container">
            <div class="input-container">
            <h1 class="center custom-countdown">Custom Alarm</h1>
                <form class="form">
                    <div class="form-example">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Title </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-example">
                        <label for="job-title" class="form-label">Select a date </label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="job-title" id="job-title" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

.fullscreen-video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    z-index: 1;
}

.component-container {
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.input-container {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    
}

.form {
    min-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-example {
    margin: 10px 0;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .component-container {
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    .form {
        min-width: unset;
        width: 350px;
        }

        
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .component-container {
        min-width: unset;
        width: 95vw;
    }

    .form {
        width: 350px;
    }
}
```

Live demo of my project: https://eloquent-wright-eb9a43.netlify.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another media query in `CSS`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
.form {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or edit the existing query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
.form {
    /* width: 350px; */
    width: 100%;
}
```